# Scrolling with a touchscreen 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen, scrolling

I am having trouble configuring the touchscreen on my Asus n550jv to scroll with one finger in web browsers, office applications, etc on Ubuntu 14.04. Oddly, scrolling works in the settings apps and a handful of other preinstalled apps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=146708

Comment: For web, I'd recommend Chrome/Chromium, it works nicely with touch screens, you can even use gestures to go back to previous page etc.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity on Lenovo Flex 2. Seems that scrolling works in Chromium and it doesn't in Firefox. The solution for scrolling in FF is Grab nad Drag addon. Still, right click remains the biggest problem as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

there is a help page on Ubuntu about this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Try `--touch-devices` in the command line parameters.

Determine X's input device id in a console by

```
xinput list
```

leading to:

```
google-chrome --touch-devices=10
```

source: 
[Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04)