# Touchscreen don't click in google chrome

Tags: touchscreen, xps

I have a xps13 developer edition with ubuntu 12.04 preinstalled, and my problem is related with the touchscreen, that it's not working properly in google chrome...

When I touch the screen the mouse/cursor is moved to that position, but it never clicked,I mean, I can't click into link, so the only interaction with the screen on chrome is move the mouse/cursor.

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04) that talks about this kind of problem. I followed these steps and it worked. But after reboot it turns off and I need to do the same steps every time and it's annoying...

Any solution for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop and change the `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` lines to `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --touch-devices=NNN` where NNN is your touch screen device. My touch screen device is 12.

Comment: It not solves my problem... but thank you

Comment: You should check the touchscreen's device id first; don't assume it is 10. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04

Comment: I know it. My touch screen device is 9...

Comment: The thing is very curious, because if I initalize chrome clicking the chrome icon with my finger in the touch screen it works, the change of the code of the desktop file is no needed...