# Touch screen scrolling on Surface Pro 3 with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, multi-touch, touchscreen

I just got Ubuntu running on my Surface and it is awesome except that scrolling is not working. Scrolling works with touchpad but not with touch screen. When I use my finger to swipe from up to down on the screen, I expect the web page to move down (just like any other touch device), but instead the touch is interpreted as a mouse click. It is the same on both Chrome and Firefox. I have tried the following:
1. installing Chrometouch plugin. It helps solve scrolling problem in webpage, but does not work when viewing pdf in Chrome.
2. I also tried this [Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04). `xinput list` output the following.

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse           id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]`

I have tired `google-chrome --touch-devices=2`, `google-chrome --touch-devices=4`, `google-chrome --touch-devices=7`, `google-chrome --touch-devices=9` but none of them works. I also went into `chrome://flags/#touch-events` and enabled touch event, but it does not work either.

How can I solve this problem? If this problem cannot be solved in Unity, are there other desktop environments that can solve it?