# Making xinput id permanent

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, xinput

I use Chrome to set up a kiosk-style application at launch, following the instructions left in this question: [Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04)

I use xinput list to figure out the ID of the device and it works fine for a time. However, Since I input the touchscreen ID manually, I lose the touch events when it changes.

Is there a way to make an ID permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who want to know, I couldn't turn an ID permanent but I could find it through `xinput list --id-only`, then created a script that used Chrome's `--touch-devices` parameter to set the device's ID

First you need to find the full name of the target device using `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Then create a bash script that stores its value and calls Chrome using `--touch-devices`

```
#!/bin/bash

# (...)

id=$(xinput list --id-only 'Virtual core XTEST pointer')
exec google-chrome --touch-devices=$id --kiosk --incognito --no-first-run http://www.google.com &
```