# Chrome 43 + Touchscreen + Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, google-chrome, touchscreen

This is a followup to [Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04/479472#479472)
Has anyone had the ability to use touch-devices on newer versions of Chrome and Ubuntu?
This seems to no longer work for me

Comment: *chrome-unstable 45* works with touch on 15.04 out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I found a combination of these answers is currently working for me. If I restart *without* the --touch-devices flag and then I navigate to chrome://restart, I get working touch.

I should note that that does not appear to include any kind of window controls (I can't drag the window around or resize it with touch), but it does fix scrolling, clicking links, clicking in the location bar, etc.

Comment: Weird indeed! I've found this doesn't work 100% of the time, either.

Comment: thanks, I went to chrome://flags/ and set "Enable touch events"  to "Automatic" and touch worked

Comment: May I ask, do you have one-finger or two-finger scrolling ? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty weird but in my case (Samsung Series 7 ULTRA, Ubuntu 15.04, Chrome 43.0.2357.65 (64-bit)) it started working after **removing** `--touch-devices=$ID` parameter.

It seems that chrome can autodetect touch devices now.

Comment: There is an option controlling this in about:flags

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus `chrome://flags/#touch-events` is something different than device id, if that's what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I own a Dell XPS 13, running Ubuntu 15.04.

Touch does not work on chrome when I start it. However, if I just restart it, by opening a tab to *chrome://restart* for example, touch will start working!